# mysqli - php - returning all results from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

There is actually alot of answers for questions like that. But everything I found around here was to Join two tables with "like" values. But that isn't what I need.

I want to query **two tables**, that is **almost exactly the same** but with **different values** inside of it.

`tbl_one` and `tbl_two` (exemple names) has "*id, title, date, content*" its just the same. But inside of `tbl_one` has differente values of `tbl_two`.

And then, it's time to query. I could make two queries calling for `tbl_one` and after `tbl_two`, but it means that I'll have to print in different "**whiles**" and I don't want this. I need to print the results in only one "while", so I thought about one query to result from different tables, is that a way to do this?

For make it straight, I need to print the results in a while like this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
// my results printed
}
```

Where `$result` is the result from the query from the two previous tables.

I tried... "select * from tbl_one, tbl_two". Life would be a lot easier if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `union all` to combine your queries i.e.

```
select * from tbl_one
union all select * from tbl_two
```